# object doesn't support property or method 'setattribute'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html2canvas

I've been trying to printed page as pdf , but haven't been able to, which causes the error **: object doesn't support property or method 'setattribute'**
at line ;  `html2canvas($(html)).find('#Content')[0],`

How to fix error ?

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("cmd").onclick = function fun() {
        alert("hello");
        exportTwo();
    }
}

function exportTwo() {
    var canvasToImage = function(canvas){
        var img = new Image();
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        img.src = dataURL;
        return img;
    };

    var canvasShiftImage = function(oldCanvas,shiftAmt){
        shiftAmt = parseInt(shiftAmt) || 0;
        if(!shiftAmt){ return oldCanvas; }
        
        var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height - shiftAmt;
        newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
        var ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
        
        var img = canvasToImage(oldCanvas);
        ctx.drawImage(img,0, shiftAmt, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        
        return newCanvas;
    };
    
    
    var canvasToImageSuccess = function(canvas){
        var pdf = new jsPDF('l','px'),
            pdfInternals = pdf.internal,
            pdfPageSize = pdfInternals.pageSize,
            pdfScaleFactor = pdfInternals.scaleFactor,
            pdfPageWidth = pdfPageSize.width,
            pdfPageHeight = pdfPageSize.height,
            totalPdfHeight = 0,
            htmlPageHeight = canvas.height,
            htmlScaleFactor = canvas.width / (pdfPageWidth * pdfScaleFactor),
            safetyNet = 0;
        
        while(totalPdfHeight < htmlPageHeight && safetyNet < 15){
            var newCanvas = canvasShiftImage(canvas, totalPdfHeight);
            pdf.addImage(newCanvas, 'png', 0, 0, pdfPageWidth, 0, null, 'NONE');
            
            totalPdfHeight += (pdfPageHeight * pdfScaleFactor * htmlScaleFactor);
            
            if(totalPdfHeight < htmlPageHeight){
                pdf.addPage();
            }
            safetyNet++;
        }
        
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
    };     
    
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://apps.group.ec/sites/Insight/en-us/Pages/Dom/dm.aspx',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
        //$('#Content').html($(data).find('#content').html());
            var html = $.parseHTML(data);
            console.log($(html).find( '#Content').html()); 
            html2canvas($(html)).find('#Content')[0], {
                onrendered: function(canvas){
                    canvasToImageSuccess(canvas);
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure **$(html)).find('#Content')[0]** returns a valid object? I assume it is **undefined**

Comment: @ gaetanoM Yes  returns html from page , I tested this way **var screenshot = {};
    html2canvas( [ document.getElementById('#Content') ], {
        onrendered: function( canvas ) {
            screenshot.img = canvas.toDataURL( "image/png" );
            screenshot.data = { 'image' : screenshot.img };
            $.ajax({
                url: "url",
                data: screenshot.data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function( result ) {
                }
            });
            }
    });**    but not work

Comment: **document.getElementById('#Content') ** should be **document.getElementById('Content') ** Can you try and let me know? Thanks

Comment: Thank you @gaetanoM but i have same error